# Error notification not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, error-handling

My problem happens to be the error, I am attempting to produce an error, in this case the error being hiding the loading symbol and showing a refresh button in order for the user to reload the page to see if the data loads this time.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#busy').show();
    $(document).bind('deviceready', function () {
        var today = $('#todaysong');

        $.ajax({
            url: 'my url',
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            jsonp: 'jsoncallback',
            timeout: 5000,
            success: function (data, status) {
                $.each(data, function (i, item) {
                    var song = '<name>' + item.name + '</name>' + '<artist>' + item.artist + '<br></artist>';
                    $('#busy').hide();

                    today.append(song);
                });
            },
            error: function (error) {
                $('#busy').fadeOut();
                $('#reload').fadeIn();
            }
        });
    });
});
```

This is my code, could someone advise on what I am doing wrong, I've tried a few things and cannot seem to get it to work, also would I make it so said button was able to refresh this individual piece of code?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: "Not working" is pretty vague: could you be clearer about what you expect to happen and what is actually happening? E.g., is the error callback running? (Does '#busy' in fact fade out, or...? If you add a `console.log('error')` or `alert('error')` as the first line of the error handler what happens?)

Answer (score 0):

In order to debug your code:

- Are you generating an error on your own? Is it really an error? Track your request via Firebug or ...
- Be sure about running the error function. Again try Firebug or such things to set break points.
- Check the JavaScript console for being sure there is no any of damn JavaScript error. And again Firebug error console.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing other details it is difficult to suggest. 
Still I'm trying.. Check the IDs of the elements you have mentioned is same as they are in HTML. Check in HTML that one id is not assigned to more than one element.

In the AJAX code remove `jsonp: 'jsoncallback',` for a while and test if it is working.

Answer (score 0):

**error(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)**

> A function to be called if the request fails. The function receives
>   three arguments: The jqXHR (in jQuery 1.4.x, XMLHttpRequest) object, a
>   string describing the type of error that occurred and an optional
>   exception object, if one occurred. Possible values for the second
>   argument (besides null) are "timeout", "error", "abort", and
>   "parsererror". When an HTTP error occurs, errorThrown receives the
>   textual portion of the HTTP status, such as "Not Found" or "Internal
>   Server Error." As of jQuery 1.5, the error setting can accept an array
>   of functions. Each function will be called in turn. Note: This handler
>   is not called for cross-domain script and JSONP requests. This is an
>   Ajax Event.

Where the important part in this case is;

> Note: This handler is not called for cross-domain script and JSONP
>   requests.

Quote from the API documentation of [jQuery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

You should instead be using `jsonpCallback`.